# React unnecessary render of element

Tags: reactjs

I've just started learning React and was putting together a small app which makes calls to a quotes API. The API has an endpoint that returns a random quote. When the app initially loads it makes a call to the API and shows a quote, and there's a button that can be clicked to get a new random quote (new call to the API).

I have a root component named App. This component has a QuoteWrap component as a child. The QuoteWrap component has two children: the button that is used to get a new random quote and a Quote component which shows the author of the quote and the quote itself. This is the code inside of the QuoteWrap component:

```
export default function QuoteWrap() {
    const { quoteData, isLoading, fireNewCall } = useQuote();

    const handleClick = () => {
        fireNewCall();
    };

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Get random quote</button>
            
            { isLoading ? 
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            :
                <Quote author={quoteData.author} quote={quoteData.quote} />
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

useQuote() is a custom hook that manages the calls to the API and returns 3 values: 1- the data, 2- if a call is in process and 3- a function to make a call to the API.

Obviously, every time the button is clicked, the whole QuoteWrap component is re-rendered (as quoteData and isLoading change). But really, the button doesn't need to be re-rendered as it never changes.

So I thought: ok, I can move the button up to the App component. But then I don't have access to the fireNewCall function in the useQuote hook.

How can I prevent the button from being re-rendered? Is it even important in this case or am I getting too obsessed with React re-renders?

Thanks!

Comment: I think You are getting too obsessed with re renders. React is pretty efficient there is no need to overdo everything

Comment: Don't be bothered with button re-render. For bigger chunks of Layout that are pointlessly re-rendered you can use a react memo function -https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  component will re-render every time the handleClick function changes, which is every time that QuoteWrap is rendered.

The solution is the useCallback hook. useCallback will return the same function to handleClick, every time QuoteWrap is rendered, so long as the dependencies haven't changed.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

You would use it like this:

```js
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    fireNewCall();
  },[fireNewCall]);
```

fireNewCall is the dependency, so as long as useQuote returns a stable fireNewCall function, then your button will not re-render, since the handleClick property hasn't changed.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. But even with useCallback, wouldn't QuoteWrap re-render every time quoteData and/or isLoading change? What I mean is, there's no way you can avoid the button from being re-renered, is there? I've seen thatt everybody that has answered my question is saying not to worry about the re-render, so I won't. Just trying to get the basic concepts clear... Basically my original question was if there is a better way of structuring things or if it is fine as it is, and just forget about the button re-render. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcos hard to say without seeing the code for useQuote(). But I assume that useQuote() propably has a useEffect() hook in it, which would cause a re-render.
However, quoteData and isLoading are both given to QuoteWrap on render, so in short, no, quoteData and isLoading would not cause a re-render. They are only read on render.  If the desire was to re-render QuoteWrap when quoteData changes, then it should be passed to QuoteWrap as a prop. prop changes cause re-renders of components.
I wouldn't worry about the button re-rendering. If fireNewCall changes, then you want the button to render.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get too obsessed with React re-renders. The button should be re-rendered because, `handleClick` should be changed when `fireNewCall` changed for some case. Even if, `handleClick` will never be changed. It's no need to think about an element re-render.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what Benjamin and Viet said - in your original code, a new function is assigned to handleClick on each render. You can use `React.useCallback` to maintain the original function reference and only update it when something in the dependency array changes - in this case, just `fireNewCall` needs to go into the dependency array.

But as Viet says, don't get too obsessed with it. Using `React.useCallback` might even slow down your code. Check out Kent C. Dodds [When to useMemo and useCallback](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) post for more insight.

Comment: I have read the article by Kent C. Dodds, and I found it helpful. However, I was annoyed by his claim that useCallback is worse or that it will slow down your code, because he basically gave examples on how not to use useCallback. A straw man argument. Obviously, if you do it wrong, you will have bad results. So instead, just use useCallback correctly and when appropriate.